# How to check that results from two ordered SQL queries match?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the problem: I have two columns in a table that, for each grouping, should have the same order. I want to check that this is true for the existing data before I make that assumption going forward.

Some example data:

```
gid  c1  c2
1    1   5
1    2   7
2    1   22
2    2   38
2    3   40
3    1   4
3    2   8
3    3   2
```

As you can see, if I were to use
`select * from table t where t.gid = 1 order by c1`
the result would be identical, and ordered identically to
`select * from table t where t.gid = 1 order by c2`.
The results would also match for gid = 2. 
However, if I were to do the same with gid = 3, the order would no longer match. because, in that case, ordering by `c2` has a different result from ordering by `c1`.

I want to check the entire table to insure that ordering by either of these columns will have the same result for each value of `gid`. Oracle's `MINUS` won't work, as it doesn't allow  `order by` in the subqueries. My first try, which doesn't work because of the limitations of `MINUS`, was:

```
select gid, c1, c2 from table order by gid, c1, c2
  minus
select gid, c1, c2 from table order by gid, c2, c1;
```

I am using oracle 11g if that helps with the answer.

Comment: `minus` doesn't work as it does an implicit `distinct` as you're only interested in whether one set is present in the other or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find difference in order in the same record by assigning [row_number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

```
with ordering as (
  select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by gid
                            order by c1) order_c1,
         row_number() over (partition by gid
                            order by c2) order_c2
  from t
)
select *
  from ordering
 where order_c1 <> order_c2
```

Comment: @Nikola, `row_number` is just the ticket. Perfect and such a fast response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, don't have Oracle but
Something like

```
Select gid,c1,c2,row_number() as rownum from ordering order by gid,c1,c2
join (select gid,c1,c2,row_number() as otherrownum from ordering order by gid,c2,c1) otherOrdering
On rownum = otherrownum and 
((ordering.gid <> otherOrdering.gid) Or
(ordering.c1 <> otherOrdering.c1) or
(ordering.c2 <> otherOrdering.c2))
```

If it returns anything your assumption is incorrect.
Or you could change <> to = and Or to AND, it should return the same number of rows as there is in the table.

I think anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the EXCEPT equivalent on Oracle. But that works just fine on MS SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle's `EXCEPT` and `MINUS` are identical, and will not accept `order by` in the sub-queries.